# How to contain large MySQL temporary Tables

Tags: mysql, temp-tables

Our application creates many and large internal temporary tables that blows up the database.I have the following `tmp_table_size` set to 768M and `max_heap_table_zise` set to 768M and `max_connections` to 1024, FYI my total mem is 66GB and I am using SSD hard disk. but when I have many people hitting the same database at once,this will result in many large tmp tables being created and this slows and blows the databases..I need help.

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you avoid creating all that temp table ?

Comment: Why are you using temporary tables, or to be more specific, why do you use that many temporary tables?

Comment: The application code has been there for  years and i   was told i can't change the application code in order to avoid many temporary tables, so the only choice i have now is to see how i can tune some mysql variables to contain the temporary tables.I NEED HELP.

Comment: @BygEynst it's not that simple.  Well, actually it *is* simple in principle -- you first have to find the actual problem. `max_heap_table_size` is only relevant to *implicit* temporary tables created and destroyed by the optimizer -- not explicit `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ...` tables.  You need to quantify "slows and blows."  Memory? Probably not. CPU? Maybe, but probably not. Disk bandwidth? Very likely. If so, you can only fix that with better hardware or better code, not configuration parameters.  We need some insight into the actual problem.

Comment: Can you do some perf tracking ? like checking you CPU load, RAM usage and disk I/O ?

Comment: When many users hit thesame database at once,many large  tmp tables are created and this  slows the server, resulting in many slow queries which eventually slow down the application.We are suing SSD which has a high IOPS..So, i was thinking if i have  RAM of 66 GB and i have tmp_tabe_size=768M and max_connections=1024 , 1024x768=786432M(786GB) of RAM , what if i reduce the max_connections or  set big_tables =on so that all the tmp tables be created on disk instead in memory..I just want to a way to tune some variables to handle this situation. I need help